# Frames order of execution

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, frame

The log out page has four frames and after the frames are executed i make a java script call to redirect the user to a different application . The four frames are the place where actually a log out happens .But sometime the user is not able to get logged out when network is slow . So i want to understand how does the net frames get executed . All execute at once or what is the order of execution ??

Comment: Frames are painful... why is your client-side code responsible for the logout? Typically that's handled by killing their session server-side.

Comment: You *can* control order of execution, see if this helps http://codecorner.galanter.net/2011/11/02/how-to-load-iframes-in-order-according-to-priority/

Comment: I am unable to open the link

Comment: @user4061 If you're just calling some scripts and you don't need the user to see it (since you're logging out and redirecting anyway) why not use AJAX?

Comment: @YuriyGalanter That code you linked to is insane.  I certainly hope that nobody ever has to use it for anything.

Comment: @Brad Sometimes all hope is lost :) That code is successfully used in a prod app to load widget iframes in order specified by user. Making fastest ones load first so the slowest one don't delay the rest

Comment: @Brad: how do i do it using AJAX ? can you suggest me some examples